# Как использовать Xna в Xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk, xna

Первые шаги в замарин студио, ещё даже не нюхал моно и xna. Нашел пару уроков и в каждом из них используются библиотеки Microsoft.Xna. Однако у меня эти библиотеки не работают ни в какую.

Xamarin studio устанавливал по инструкции https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_Java_SDK_(JDK) 
И GTK устанавливал по той же инструкции. 
Как решить проблему? 
[image: Скрин зэмарин студио]

Comment: Полагаю, необходимо добавить Проект/добавить пакеты NuGet? Но какие?

Comment: Да ну нафиг! И правда добавление пакетов NuGet помогло. Ну что ж это за ребусы то такие. Вот как догадаться человеку, который до этого только на паскале программульки писал.

Comment: Не надо ребусы решать. Установили бы Visual Studio и у вас в придачу был бы установленный XAMARIN "из коробки".

Comment: Разработка и поддержка XNA уже прекращена. Так что особо не вкладывайтесь в её изучение.